# Discord PY: How can I take an Audio MP3 URL and play it in a voice channel?

Tags: python, url, audio, discord.py, mp3

https://onlyconnect.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/Audio/s16e2-11-Toyah-Brave+New+World.mp3

I'm trying to make a discord bot that plays certain mp3 files hosted online in a voice channel on request. I have the following audio file which is easily callable but none of the audio source classes in Discord PY  which can be played using voice_client.play() seem to work:

For example:

```
voiceclient.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("https://onlyconnect.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/Audio/s16e2-11-Toyah-Brave+New+World.mp3"))
```

leads to the exception:

```
Command raised an exception: ClientException: ffmpeg was not found.
```

I don't really understand what the different audio source building objects represent. According to the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#pcmaudio), the PCMAUDIO object "reads byte data representing raw PCM." but I cannot find anywhere to convert an mp3 into raw byte data representing PCM so I am still stumped.

Answer (score 0):

you've to download `ffmpeg.exe` and add it to Your system path. and then you can use it.
Example:-

```py
ctx.voice_client.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(url, executable='C:/programs/ffmpeg.exe'))
```

You must add the full path(root path) of ffmpeg.exe file

download link: https://ffmpeg.org/download.html